# Find how many RecyclerView items fit screen before creation

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Basically, I'm trying to programatically find out how many items are going to fit in a RecyclerView (and be visible to user, of course) in order to determine how many of them to fetch from cache.

I'm using a LinearLayoutManager.

Also, I'm aware of the LinearLayoutManager method findLastVisibleItemPosition, but obviously it's useless in this case since we're talking on before-initialization time, not after (so it returns -1).

Tried reading the docs or thinking on a creative but efficient idea, but I got nothing on my mind.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds actually pretty interesting, but only works if your height (vertical scroll) or width (horizontal scroll) is fixed, meaning no wrap_content.

<s>No sample code and nothing tested here:</s>

1. Create an Adapter with a setter for `getCount` that gets returned in case your data-source is null/empty
2. in `getCount` return at least 1 if your data is empty/null
3. make sure `onBindViewHolder()` can handle empty/non-existent data
4. add a `OnChildAttachStateChangeListener` to your RecyclerView, everytime the listener gets called, use the `view` to `view.post(new Runnable() {...increase adapters getCount...adapter.notifyItemInserted()}` (that runnable is necessary to avoid crash+burn)
5. `OnChildAttachStateChangeListener` gets called again >>> compare `getCount` and `findLastVisibleItemPosition`. If `getCount > findLastVisibleItemPosition + 1` remove that listener. The number of fixed-size views fitting into ListView is `findLastVisibleItemPosition + 1`
6. Get your data and set it into you adapter, call `notifyDataSetChanged`
7. make sure `getCount` returns the data-source length from now on.

you could hide the listview behind a loadingscreen, or you can set the child views to invisible in `onBindViewHolder`

EDIT:

1. Create an Adapter which returns a ridiculous high count when no data is set and make sure it handles missing data correctly in `onBindViewHolder`
2. Extend `LinearLayoutManager` and Override `onLayoutChildren()` after the super call if `getItemCount() > getChildCount()` getChildCount() is the number of Views that would be visible in your RecyclerView

MainActivity.class

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private PreCountingAdapter mAdapter;
        private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
        private PreCountLinearLayoutManager mPreCountLayoutManager;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            mPreCountLayoutManager = new PreCountLinearLayoutManager(this,
                    LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
            mPreCountLayoutManager.setListener(new PreCountLinearLayoutManager.OnPreCountedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPreCounted(int count) {
                    mPreCountLayoutManager.setListener(null);
                    loadData(count);
                }
            });
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mPreCountLayoutManager);
            mAdapter = new PreCountingAdapter();
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }

        private void loadData(final int visibleItemCount) {
            // load data here, probably asynchronously,
            // for simplicity just an String Array with size visibleItemCount
            final List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < visibleItemCount; i++) {
                data.add(String.format("child number #%d", i));
            }
            mRecyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mAdapter.swapData(data);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            mPreCountLayoutManager.setListener(null);
            super.onDestroy();
        }
    }
```

PreCountLinearLayoutManager.class

```
    public class PreCountLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
        private OnPreCountedListener mListener;

        public interface OnPreCountedListener {
            void onPreCounted(int count);
        }

        public PreCountLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
            super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLayoutChildren(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
            super.onLayoutChildren(recycler, state);
            if (getItemCount() > getChildCount()) {
                if (mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onPreCounted(getChildCount());
                }
            }
        }

        public void setListener(OnPreCountedListener listener) {
            mListener = listener;
        }
    }
```

PreCountingAdapter.class

```
    public class PreCountingAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PreCountingAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        private List<String> mData;

        public void swapData(List<String> data) {
            mData = data;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            View mItemView;
            TextView mTextView;

            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                mTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
                mItemView = itemView;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            return new ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_child, parent, false));
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            if (mData == null) {
                // we are in precounting stage
                holder.mItemView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                String item = mData.get(position);
                holder.mItemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.mTextView.setText(item);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mData == null ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : mData.size();
        }

    }
```

Comment: I tested it, won't work since the last View never gets attached. (Doh, should have been obvious to me while writing)

Comment: Added another solution, tested it briefly and it works so far.

Comment: What do you mean fixed? It's never fixed, it always spans on almost all available space (match_parent), like most of the views in Android.
Also, can you please explain better why your solution should work?

P.S. I think an easier method would be to calculate in real time the height of the recycler view and devide by the height of each item (which then needs to be set programatically or from a dimension xml, so it will be available before the creation of the item itself...)

Comment: With Fixed, I mean each child view has to have a fixed height, independent from the data to be displayed. e.g. the textview has always 2 lines of text, the RecyclerView itself can be match_parent, that's not a problem. While you could calculate each item height and simply figure out the count, it quickly gets complicated when you start taking margins, paddings, decorators etc into account.

Comment: My solution on the other hand simply tricks LinearLayoutManager to do exactly the work it always does: layout out child views until the RecyclerView is filled. Also there is almost no overhead, since the child views get recycled and reused when the real data comes in. You can still change font sizes, line numbers etc. and it will still work.